# Is it possible to install the security update without installing the update preview?

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-pro

I would like to install the security intelligence update but not the update preview. Is that possible?  Is there something I've neglected to do in my update configuration that is causing these two updates to be treated as a unit?

[image: Microsoft update]

Comment: [Yes])https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/defenderupdates);  You can install it manually.  You can also hide the update using the appropriate tool.  You can also download the signature update from the same linked page.

Comment: you can also install the update patch manually in the microsoft update catalog: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=update+rollups

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Framework updates are security and necessary updates, so there is no preview for them. I am not sure why they say preview in the title line, because these updates need to be done before more .NET updates come along.

Further, the updates have been downloaded and prepared for install, so you need to install at the earliest opportunity for you because other updates to other apps cannot proceed at this point.

So just do the install. The .NET updates work on my machines here without issue.

Also Microsoft has begun forcing Windows 1903 machines to update to V1909

[ZDNet Article](https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-microsoft-starts-forcing-windows-10-1903-pcs-up-to-version-1909-not-20h2/?ftag=TRE-03-10aaa6b&bhid=23164040498209351948461508422926&mid=13158792&cid=716451735)

With support for Windows 10 version 1903 coming to an end on December 8, Microsoft has started pushing 1903 users to Windows 10 version 1909.

So this is just part of that process.